# Simplifying an expression with complex conjugates

Tags: complex, assumptions

I have been unable to do the following. First I make an assumption `$Assumptions = x \[Element] Reals;` and define `U=u[0][t]+ x u[1][t]]` and I want to simplify `Conjugate[U]`

to

`Conjugate[u[0][t]]+ x Conjugate[u[1][t]]`

Using `Simplify` leaves the original expression unchanged.

Using `ComplexExpand` in its simplest form assumes everything is real. The more complex command

`ComplexExpand[Conjugate[U,  NotElement[u[0][t], Reals] && NotElement[u[1][t], Reals]]`

give the same response.

Comment: How about `ComplexExpand[Conjugate[U], {_[t]}, TargetFunctions -> Conjugate]`?

Comment: Thank you. That works. Would you be willing to explain briefly what this means?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complex conjugation is distributive over addition, but `Simplify` doesn't try that particular transformation. If you do that step yourself you get the expected result:

```
Simplify[Distribute[Conjugate[U]]]
(* Conjugate[u[0][t]] + x Conjugate[u[1][t]] *)
```

You could also use `ComplexExpand`. The second argument specifies a pattern for variables to treat as complex, in this case anything but `x` should be considered complex:

```
ComplexExpand[Conjugate[U], Except[x], TargetFunctions -> Conjugate]
(* Conjugate[u[0][t]] + x Conjugate[u[1][t]] *)
```

As a side note, it's worth pointing out that your preferred expression is actually *less* simple than the original, according to Mathematica's default measure of complexity. So Simplify wouldn't have returned it even if it tried the necessary transformation:

```
LeafCount[Conjugate[u[0][t] + x u[1][t]]]
(* 10 *)

LeafCount[Conjugate[u[0][t]] + x Conjugate[u[1][t]]]
(* 11 *)
```